# Cannot login in IE

Tags: 7, users

I have a simple Drupal site.

I was able to login using Chrome, now I'm not.

I can login with Firefox.

I found [this discussion](https://drupal.org/node/972504) suggesting I should look at the sessions table.  I deleted all sessions for the admin user (UID:1) but still cannot login with Chrome and still can login from Firefox.  My Time on Client & Server are reasonably close in time.

I am on Drupal 7.15

Any Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried this- repair the broken session mysql table via phpmyadmin or mysql command line

Comment: 1) Tell us what changed when you lost your ability to log in. 2) Are new sessions created at all or not? 3) are session cookies set and sent back to server?

Comment: there are three answers for your issue - its with in link you mentioned, read it fully